# Java JTextField cannot type

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextfield

I have looked around all the threads on this subject, and I could not find a way to fix my problem.

I have a list of JPanels with some containing a JTextField.
The other panels with JButtons and JCheckboxes work perfectly.

[image: SamplerSorter ActionEditor]

The JTextField is selecteable, but I can't type in it. Here is the code used to generate the panel

```
        setSize(new Dimension(450, 33));

        JLabel lblPrefix = new JLabel(propertyToEdit.prefix);
        lblPrefix.setBounds(12, 16, 56, 16);
        add(lblPrefix);

        JTextField stringInputField = new JTextField();
        stringInputField.setEnabled(true);
        stringInputField.setEditable(true);
        stringInputField.setBounds(80, 13, 135, 22);
        stringInputField.setColumns(10);
        add(stringInputField);
```

Here's the code on Github for the foolhardy :)

[See code on Github](https://github.com/iObsidian/SamplerSorter/blob/35c39b71ba6eb9deec5c306398b9202dafb80c99/src/samplerSorter/actions/editeable/EditPropertyPanel.java)

Comment: `Here's the code on Github` - the code should be posted here in the forum in the form of a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Note, I don't like seeing all the setBounds() statements(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: My guess is, either it's the use of null layouts or the window is not focusable

Comment: Well, I can focus on the panel and the textfield, but I'll investigate the null layout possibility

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! It was because of this code

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher
```

On [github](https://github.com/iObsidian/AudioSampleSorter/blob/35c39b71ba6eb9deec5c306398b9202dafb80c99/src/samplerSorter/macro/macroedit/MacroEditorUI.java#L196).